# Zend framework complains that "There is already an active transaction"

Tags: mysql, zend-framework, transactions, zend-db

we are using zend_db_table and we are having some issues since Zend Framework is complaining about two transactions being active:

```
[message:protected] => There is already an active transaction
[string:Exception:private] => 
[code:protected] => 0
[file:protected] => /var/www/vhosts/test.local/private/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php
[line:protected] => 305
[trace:Exception:private] => Array
```

This is the code in the Controller:

```
     public function convertAction()
{
    $this->setNoRender();

    // If the quote is a copy of a previous one, fetch all the datas
    $quoteId = Zend_Filter::filterStatic($this->getRequest()->getParam('qte_id'), 'int');
    $quoteTable = new Model_QuotesTable();
    $quoteRow = $quoteTable->findById($quoteId);
    if (count($quoteRow)) {
        $clonedId = $quoteRow->convertToJob();
        $this->flashMessageRedirect('Quotation successfully converted', '/jobs/edit/job_id/' . $clonedId);
    } else {
        $this->flashMessageRedirect('Unable to find the quote to be converted', '/quotes');
    }
}
```

which is recalling this function in QuotesTableRow which extends zend_db_table_abstract:

```
    public function convertToJob()
{
    $db = $this->_getTable()->getAdapter();
    $db->beginTransaction();

    $jobsTable = new Model_JobsTable();

    try {

        /*
         * Update the status of the old row to match the $status passed into this function
         */
        $this->qte_status = "Accepted";
        $this->save();

        /*
         * Create new row with the same details as above
         */

        $newRow = $jobsTable->createRow();

        $newRow->job_title = $this->qte_title;
        $newRow->job_cus_id = $this->qte_cus_id;
        $newRow->job_enq_id = $this->qte_enq_id;
        $newRow->job_qte_id = $this->qte_id;
        $newRow->job_title = $this->qte_title;
        $newRow->job_description = $this->qte_description;
        $newRow->job_work_location_id = $this->qte_work_location_id;
        $newRow->job_work_category_id = $this->qte_work_category_id;
        $newRow->job_work_type_id = $this->qte_work_type_id;
        $newRow->job_cus_code = $this->qte_cus_code;
        $newRow->job_cus_name = $this->qte_cus_name;
        $newRow->job_wt_ref_code = $this->qte_wt_ref_code;
        $newRow->job_wt_description = $this->qte_wt_description;
        $newRow->job_wl_code = $this->qte_wl_code;
        $newRow->job_wl_description = $this->qte_wl_description;
        $newRow->job_wc_ref_code = $this->qte_wc_ref_code;
        $newRow->job_wc_description = $this->qte_wc_description;
        $newRow->job_qte_title = $this->qte_title;
        $newRow->job_datetime_created = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

        $newRowId = $newRow->save();

        $db->commit();
        return $newRowId;
    } 
    catch (Exception $e) { 
        $db->rollback(); 

        echo('<pre>');
        print_r($e);
        echo('</pre>');
        exit();

        throw new Exception($e->getMessage());
        return false;
    }
}
```

in addition, it seems to be related to the model we are not in since if we comment the row with the save() function related to the Model_JobsTable() the script is working, while it returns the same error when we comment the other save().

Answer (score 6):

This error is being returned from MySQL and ZF is only telling you the error message.

Are you starting two transactions in the same request?  That can explain why you got this error message, or you could have had an aborted connection that was in the middle of a transaction and it didn't get rolled back or auto-committed.

You should only start one transaction per database connection.  If you need two models to have an active transaction in a single request, then you need to get 2 separate database connections.

See [this (great) answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/319939/892493) by Bill Karwin in regards to this issue.

You can run the query `SHOW ENGINE InnoDB STATUS;` to get a list of active transactions.  If you have one that is open and you have no active transactions from PHP/ZF, then try closing that transaction, otherwise you'll have to look into your code and see how two transactions are getting started in the same request.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for your answer, we found a solution.
The problem was that, we were using the `save()` function twice; changing the first `save()` with an `insert()`, solved the problem:

```
public function convertToJob()
{

    $db = $this->_getTable()->getAdapter();
    $db->beginTransaction();

    $jobsTable = new Model_JobsTable();

    try {

        /*
         * Create new row with the same details as above
         */

        $data = array(
            'job_cus_id'            =>  $this->qte_cus_id,
            'job_enq_id'            =>  $this->qte_enq_id,
            'job_qte_id'            =>  $this->qte_id,
            'job_title'             =>  $this->qte_title,
            'job_description'       =>  $this->qte_description,
            'job_work_location_id'  =>  $this->qte_work_location_id,
            'job_work_category_id'  =>  $this->qte_work_category_id,
            'job_work_type_id'      =>  $this->qte_work_type_id,
            'job_cus_code'          =>  $this->qte_cus_code,
            'job_cus_name'          =>  $this->qte_cus_name,
            'job_wt_ref_code'       =>  $this->qte_wt_ref_code,
            'job_wt_description'    =>  $this->qte_wt_description,
            'job_wl_code'           =>  $this->qte_wl_code,
            'job_wl_description'    =>  $this->qte_wl_description,
            'job_wc_ref_code'       =>  $this->qte_wc_ref_code,
            'job_wc_description'    =>  $this->qte_wc_description,
            'job_qte_title'         =>  $this->qte_title,
            'job_datetime_created'  =>  date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
        );

        $newRowId = $jobsTable->insert($data);

        /*
         * Update the status of the old row to match the $status passed into this function
         */

        $this->qte_status = "Accepted";
        $this->save();

        $db->commit();

        return $newRowId;
    } 
    catch (Exception $e) {
        throw new Exception($e->getMessage());
        return false;
    }
}
```