# PHP and MySQLi check if in transaction

Tags: php, mysql, transactions, mysqli, memcached

Is there any way to get if currently I'm inside of any transaction? For example: get if MySqli::autocommit is 'on' or 'off'?

Need this because my project is using memcache, which should only be updated once all transaction success. I wanna assert user is not invoking update cache method in the process of any transaction.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do detect that transaction has already been started?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/319788/how-do-detect-that-transaction-has-already-been-started)

Comment: Even if you `select@@autocommit`, it would return `0` if you start a transaction using `begin` or `start transaction`.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a foolproof way to find out if a transaction has been started because, even if you usually use MySqli::autocommit to start one, someone could always issue the SQL to start a transaction. See the answers here:

[How do detect that transaction has already been started?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/319788/how-do-detect-that-transaction-has-already-been-started)