# PDO losing Transaction before commit/rollback

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo, transactions

I am trying to use transactions with mysql using PDO to do the work. The problem I am having is the transaction is breaking before I get to the commit. I know this because I am echo the inTransaction() function on the connection.

It appears to me that the reason for this is I am instantiating a PDODatabase class and then I do some other coding work before actually executing any queries at which time I lose the transaction.

Instantiating my class

```
$pdo = new PdoDatabase;
$pdo->beginTransaction();
echo "first ".$pdo->transactionStarted()."<br />";
```

The PdoDatabase class

```
public function __construct(){
    $dsn = 'mysql:host='.DB_HOST.';dbname='.DB_NAME;
    $options = array(PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => TRUE, PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    try{
        $this->_connection = new PDO($dsn, DB_USER, BD_PASS, $options);
    } catch (PDOException $e){
        $this->_error = $e->getMessage();
    }
}

public function query($q){
    if($this->_error != ''){
        echo $this->_error;
    } else {
        $this->_stmt = $this->_connection->prepare($q);
    }
}

public function bind($param, $value, $type = null){
    //echo "<br>".$value."<br>";
    if (is_null($type)) {
      switch (true) {
        case is_int($value):
          $type = PDO::PARAM_INT;
          break;
        case is_bool($value):
          $type = PDO::PARAM_BOOL;
          break;
        case is_null($value):
          $type = PDO::PARAM_NULL;
          break;
        default:
          $type = PDO::PARAM_STR;
      }
    }
    $this->_stmt->bindValue($param, $value, $type);
}

public function execute($class = null){
    $object_array = array();

    if($class !== null){
        if($this->_stmt->execute()){
            $this->_stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_CLASS | PDO::FETCH_PROPS_LATE, $class, null);
            while($row = $this->returnRow()){
                $object_array[] = $class::instantiate($row);
            }
        }
        return $object_array;
    } else {

        return $this->_stmt->execute();
    }
}

public function transactionStarted(){
    return $this->_connection->inTransaction();
}
```

How I am using it (portion)

```
if(isset($_POST['id']) && $_POST['id'] != ''){
                echo "id exists ".$pdo->transactionStarted()."<br />";
                $bidder->getBidderById($_POST['id']);
                echo "step 1 ".$pdo->transactionStarted()."<br />";
                $bidder = $bidder->getList(0);
                echo "step 2 ".$pdo->transactionStarted()."<br />";
                $old_bidder = clone $bidder;
                echo "step 3 ".$pdo->transactionStarted()."<br />";

                $bidder_phones->getPhones($_POST['id']);
                echo "step 4 ".$pdo->transactionStarted()."<br />";
                $bidder_phones = $bidder_phones->getList();
                echo "step 5 ".$pdo->transactionStarted()."<br />";
                if($_POST['phone'] == ''){
                    // check to see if there are any phone numbers in the database already and delete if there is
                    foreach($bidder_phones as $bp){
                        $q = "delete from bidder_phones where id = :id";
                        $pdo->query($q);
                        $pdo->bind(":id", $bp->getId());
                        $pdo->execute();
                        //$bp->remove();
                    }
                } else {
                    echo "phone to check ".$pdo->transactionStarted()."<br />";
                    $old_phone_numbers = array();
                    $new_phone_numbers = explode(',', $_POST['phone']);
                    foreach($bidder_phones as $bp){
                        // remove any unused phone numbers
                        if(!in_array($bp, $new_phone_numbers)){
                            $q = "delete from bidder_phones where id = :id";
                            $pdo->query($q);
                            $pdo->bind(":id", $bp->getId());
                            $pdo->execute();
                            //$bp->remove();
                        }
                        // push to an array to test the new numbers
                        array_push($old_phone_numbers, $bp->getPhone());
                    }
                    foreach($new_phone_numbers as $phone){
                        // adding new phone numbers
                        if(!in_array($phone, $old_phone_numbers)){
                            $new_phone = new BidderPhone;
                            $new_phone->setPhone($phone);
                            $new_phone->setBidderId($_POST['id']);
                            $pdo->save('BidderPhones', $new_phone);
                            //$new_phone->save();
                        }
                    }
                }
```

As you can see I am echo the $pdo->transactionStarted() several times. This is an attempt to see when I lose the transaction. What I expect to see is my message followed by a 1 to show that the transaction is still active. This is what I get:

```
first 1
id exists 1
step 1
step 2
step 3
step 4
step 5
phone to check
in save
before create

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'clickbid.bidder_phoneses' doesn't exist' in /var/www/classes/PdoDatabase.php:59 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/classes/PdoDatabase.php(59): PDOStatement->execute() #1 /var/www/classes/PdoDatabase.php(158): PdoDatabase->execute() #2 /var/www/classes/PdoDatabase.php(187): PdoDatabase->getFields('BidderPhones') #3 /var/www/classes/PdoDatabase.php(176): PdoDatabase->create('BidderPhones', Object(BidderPhone), false) #4 /var/www/admin/data/post_data.php(284): PdoDatabase->save('BidderPhones', Object(BidderPhone)) #5 {main} thrown in /var/www/classes/PdoDatabase.php on line 59
```

so I am losing the transaction right after the id exists, is this because I am doing other programming and not preparing queries and executing them? Is there something else I need to know about that I am missing? I have been working on this for the better part of the last 2 days trying to figure this out. Problem is I really need to be able to begin my transaction and do some work before actually executing some queries. Is there a way to be able to do this?

Thanks in advance for any help.

EDIT
So I made some major changes to the code and have been able to determine more closely when I am losing the active transaction.

My save method looks like this

```
public function save($table, $object, $old_object = null){
    echo "in save ".$this->transactionStarted()."<br />";
    if($object->_id != ''){
        echo "before update ".$this->transactionStarted()."<br />";
        //return $this->update($table, $object, $old_object, $transaction);
        if($this->update($table, $object, $old_object)){
            echo "update true ".$this->transactionStarted()."<br />";
            return true;
        } else {
            echo "update false ".$this->transactionStarted()."<br />";
            return false;
        }
    } else {
        echo "before create ".$this->transactionStarted()."<br />";
        //return $this->create($table, $object, $transaction);
        if($this->create($table, $object)){
            echo "create true ".$this->transactionStarted()."<br />";
            return true;
        } else {
            echo "create false ".$this->transactionStarted()."<br />";
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

In this particular case there is an _id coming from the object so $this->update is what we are debugging here is the update method

```
private function update($table, $object, $old){
    echo "in update ".$this->transactionStarted()."<br />";
    $audit = new PdoDatabase;
    echo "after new ".$this->transactionStarted()."<br />";
    $aq = "insert into audit_trails 
            (table_name, table_id, user_id, field_name, original_value, new_value) values
            (:table_name, :table_id, :user_id, :field_name, :original_value, :new_value)";
    echo "before query ".$this->transactionStarted()."<br />";
    $audit->query($aq);
    echo "after query ".$this->transactionStarted()."<br />";
    //$update = new PdoDatabase;    

    $binding = array();
    echo "before field_names ".$this->transactionStarted()."<br />";
    $field_names = self::getFields($table);
    echo "after field_names ".$this->transactionStarted()."<br />";

    $uc = new UserConfig;
    $uc->getConfig();
    $user = $uc->getList(0);
    echo "before foreach ".$this->transactionStarted()."<br />";
    foreach($field_names as $field){
        $thisField = "_".$field['Field']."<br>";
        $getField = 'get'.self::to_camel_case($field['Field']);
        $method = $getField;
        $class = self::to_camel_case($table);
        $field_list = '';

        if($field['Field'] == 'id'){
            $where = 'where id = :id';
            $binding[':id'] = ($object->$getField());
        } else {

            if(method_exists($class, $method)){
                if($object->$getField() != $old->$getField()){
                    $field_list .= $field['Field']."= :".$field['Field'].", ";
                    $binding[':'.$field['Field']] = $object->$getField();

                    $audit->bind(':table_name', $table);
                    $audit->bind(':table_id', $object->getId());
                    $audit->bind(':user_id', $user->getUserId());
                    $audit->bind(':field_name', $thisField);
                    $audit->bind(':original_value', $object->$getField());
                    $audit->bind(':new_value', $old->$getField());

                    echo "before audit execute ".$this->transactionStarted()."<br />";
                    $audit->execute();
                    echo "after audit execute ".$this->transactionStarted()."<br />";

                }
            }
        }
    }
    echo "before binding ".$this->transactionStarted()."<br />";
    if(count($binding) > 1){
        $q = "update ".self::singularToPlural($table)." set ";
        foreach($binding as $key => $value){
            if($key != ':id'){
                $q .= str_replace(':', '', $key)." = ".$key.", ";
            }
        }
        $q = rtrim($q, ", ");
        $q .= ' '.$where;

        //$update->query($q);
        echo "before this query ".$this->transactionStarted()."<br />";
        $this->query($q);
        echo "after this query ".$this->transactionStarted()."<br />";
        /*if($transaction && !$this->_stmt->inTransaction()){
            $this->_stmt->beginTransaction();
        }*/

        foreach($binding as $key => $value){
            //$update->bind($key, $value);
            $this->bind($key, $value);
        }
        //$update->bind($id);
        //return $update->execute();
        echo "before this execute ".$this->transactionStarted()."<br />";
        $stupid = $this->execute();
        echo "after this execute ".$this->transactionStarted()."<br />";
        return $stupid;
    } else {
        echo "before return true ".$this->transactionStarted()."<br />";
        return true;
    }

}
```

and the output is

```
first 1
in save 1
before update 1
in update 1
after new 1
before query 1
after query 1
before field_names 1
before execute 1
after execute 1
after field_names 1
before foreach 1
before audit execute 1
before execute 1
after execute 1
after audit execute 1
before binding 1
before this query 1
after this query 1
before this execute 1
before execute 1
after execute 1
after this execute 1
update true
the save 1
second
after save
before commit

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'There is no active transaction' in /var/www/classes/PdoDatabase.php:86 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/classes/PdoDatabase.php(86): PDO->commit() #1 /var/www/admin/data/post_data.php(403): PdoDatabase->commit() #2 {main} thrown in /var/www/classes/PdoDatabase.php on line 86
```

From this I am able to see that the active transaction is lost when we return from the update to save methods, I am just uncertain why this is.

Thanks again.

EDIT adding the getBidderById function

```
public function getBidderById($bidder_id){
    $pdo = new PdoDatabase;

    $q = "select *
            from bidders Bidder
            where Bidder.id = :bidder_id
            limit 1";

    $pdo->query($q);
    $pdo->bind(":bidder_id", $bidder_id);
    $this->_bidders = $pdo->execute('Bidder');

    if(!empty($this->_bidders)){
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

EDIT adding the create method

```
private function create($table, $object){
    //$insert = new PdoDatabase;

    $field_names = self::getFields($table);

    foreach($field_names as $field){
        $getField = 'get'.self::to_camel_case($field['Field']);
        $method = $getField;
        $class = self::to_camel_case($table);

        if(method_exists($class, $method)){
            if($field['Field'] != 'id'){
                $fields = $field['Field'].", ";
                $binding_fields = ":".$field['Field'].", ";
                $binding[':'.$field['Field']] = $object->$getField();
            }
        }
    }
    $fields = rtrim($fields, ", ");
    $binding_fields = rtrim($binding_fields, ", ");

    $iq = "insert into ".self::singularToPlural($table)." 
            (".$fields.") values 
            (".$binding_fields.")";
    $this->query($iq);
    /*if($transaction && !$this->_stmt->inTransaction()){
        $this->_stmt->beginTransaction();
    }*/

    foreach($binding as $key => $value){
        $this->bind($key, $value);
    }

    if($this->execute()){
        $object->setId($this->getConnection()->lastInsertId());
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }

}
```

Comment: What happens in $bidder-<getBidderById()

Comment: $bidder->getBidderById($_POST['id']) queries the database for this bidder, it populates the bidder instance which will be used later to update bidder if anything is different, hence the $old_bidder = clone $bidder. Both of these are passed to the save method and compared to each other to determine what needs to be updated.

Comment: There are no DDL statements involved?, can you show the function?

Comment: You have an uncaught fatal error, of course you're going to "lose" your transaction - when PHP shuts down it'll close the DB connection which'll rollback any transactions.

Comment: the commit is causing the fatal error. The fatal error is happening because I "lose" the transaction before I get to the commit.

Answer (score 0):

Hmz, I notice that you're instantiating PdoDatabase within a function and you use $this->transactionStarted().

Probally not being a problem, but since you're using a persistent connection it may be possible that you start a new transaction in some other class, which causes a implicit commit of the running transaction.

```
    if($this->create($table, $object)){
        echo "create true ".$this->transactionStarted()."<br />";
        return true;
    }
```

If use a DDL statement (CREATE, ALTER, DROP, TRUNCATE etc) in this function a commit will also be applied

Comment: I see what your saying but I lose the active transaction not at that point, which I would suspect to do so, but at the point where I am going back to the original call.

Comment: create is not being used that is just my method name. the only thing done in this method is an insert into I will add that to my post above in a second.

Answer (score 0):

Some statements in MySQL cause an implicit commit. Any transaction you may have in progress is committed. All DDL statements do this, for example.  See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/implicit-commit.html for more information on that.

It's surprisingly hard to know whether you have an active transaction in your session. Between statements that cause implicit commit, and the possibilities that a query can be "COMMIT" (not passing through any commit() function, but passing through the query() function instead), the client can not know for sure if they still have a transaction going.

This problem is kind of the bane of developers who are trying to create a reusable DBAL.

See also my answer to [How do detect that transaction has already been started?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/319788/how-do-detect-that-transaction-has-already-been-started)

---

Re comment:

For MySQL, `PDO::inTransaction()` is *not* reliable, because the PDO mysql driver doesn't implement a method `mysql_handle_in_transaction()`. There's no support in the [MySQL C API](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/c-api.html) for interrogating the transaction state of the current session.

Therefore the PDO class tries to make its best guess by using an internal variable that is set to 1 when you call `$dbh->beginTransaction()`, and set to 0 when you call `$dbh->commit()` or `$dbh->rollback()`.

But then if a DDL statement causes an implicit commit, the driver doesn't have any notification that the transaction ended. So the internal variable in PDO can become out of sync with reality. This can also happen if you call `$dbh->query('COMMIT')`, bypassing the PDO functions for transaction control.

Other PDO drivers, for example the PostgreSQL driver, do implement a means to get the current transaction state.

---

I'm not saying this is the cause of your problem in this case. But trying to detect transaction state in the client is not going to work all the time.

I can't tell what's happening in your case. You still have a few lines of your debug output for which you haven't shared the code.

Comment: so are you saying that the inTransaciton() method for the connection is not reliable? Because I am using it and it appears to be working to me, it returns 1 (or true) if I am in a transaction. Which from all my examples above show that it is happening. That is why I feel that the transaction is breaking after I execute the query statement and return to the caller which doesn't make sense to me because nothing happens except true is returned (assuming the execute was successful) and the transaction was still active just before the return