# Restrict file upload of html.erb file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, file-upload, simple-form

How do I restrict a file upload input field so that only `html.erb` files are accepted?

I have an input field like the following:

```
<%= f.input :upload_field, as: :file, label: false %>
```

I know the `accept` setting can control this inside an `input_html` tag but I am not sure how to implement it correctly.

Comment: I'd suggest checking out this answer. Might be inline with what you're looking to do.  This answer shows client side checking as well as server side which would be needed if you really want to trash anything coming in that isn't the specified filetype. http://stackoverflow.com/a/4680972/3366016

Comment: Ok, I might have to go that route because I don't see .erb in the list of MIME types: https://www.sitepoint.com/web-foundations/mime-types-complete-list//