# how to set only zip and rar in my form

Tags: html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [File input 'accept' attribute - is it useful?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/181214/file-input-accept-attribute-is-it-useful)

if i click upload button it will  show only zip file and rar file in  form
 this is showing all files.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<form action=""    method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="forms" id="file_upload"> 

<input type="file" name="file" id="file" accept='application/zip,application/rar' multiple="" >


<button type="submit">Upload</button> 

<div class="file_upload_label" id="pointer">Click here To As Zips/Rars</div> 

</form> 
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: *related:* http://stackoverflow.com/questions/181214/file-input-accept-attribute-is-it-useful

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/254184/filter-extensions-in-html-form-upload