# Validation using Html.Telerik().Upload() with MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, telerik

I am looking for sample code that would show how to set validation on the `Html.Telerik().Upload()` function so that the user can only upload `.jpg` files. I'd like to support just `.jpg` files.

Does anyone have any good examples or websites that I could use?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, filtering the extensions is not possible using **Html.Telerik().Upload()** due to the way browsers implement the `<input type="file" />`.

Source:
http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-ajax/upload/how-to-filter-out-unwanted-file-types-radupload.aspx

But, there is an alternative to do that with html and javascript:

HTML

```
<input name="fileToUpload" type="file" onchange="check_file()" >
```

javascript

```
function check_file(){
            str=document.getElementById('fileToUpload').value.toUpperCase();
    suffix=".JPG";
    suffix2=".JPEG";
    if(!(str.indexOf(suffix, str.length - suffix.length) !== -1||
                   str.indexOf(suffix2, str.length - suffix2.length) !== -1)){
    alert('File type not allowed,\nAllowed file: *.jpg,*.jpeg');
        document.getElementById('fileToUpload').value='';
    }
}
```

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6788623/1304064

Answer (score 0):

Please see the following Code. This code only accept jpeg/jpg, png format image. Also image size is restricted to 100KB.

```
@(Html.Telerik().Upload()
        .Name("EmployeeImageUpload")
        .Multiple(false)
        .Async(async => async
        .Save("SaveEmployeeImage", "Employee")
        .AutoUpload(false)
        )
        .ClientEvents(events => events
        .OnLoad("onLoad")
        .OnSelect("onSelect")
        .OnSuccess("onSuccess")
        )
    )


<script type="text/javascript">

    function onLoad(e) {
        $(this).find("input").attr("accept", "image\/jpeg,image\/jpg,image\/png");
    }

    function onSelect(e) {

        if (e.files[0].size > 102400) {
            alert('Image Size Should Be <= 100KB');
            e.preventDefault();
            return false;
        }            

        var ext =e.files[0].extension.toLowerCase();
        if ($.inArray(ext, ['.jpeg', '.jpg', '.png']) == -1) {
            alert('Only Supported Extension are jpeg/jpg, png');
            e.preventDefault();
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
</script>
```