# How can i accept all the file types except for dangerous file extensions in HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have seen the accept="images/png, videos/*" something like that, but it just take the images videos audios and some stuff, how can i exclude those dangerous file extensions like .EXE .COM .DOCM .scr .hta and more...

please help me im newbie here

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/254184/filter-extensions-in-html-form-upload

Comment: possible duplicate of [File input 'accept' attribute - is it useful?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/181214/file-input-accept-attribute-is-it-useful)

Comment: Im sorry for this post, i've got my answer from fiddler now.. thank you for all of your concerns :) very very sorry i don't know how to close this thread though... me newbie...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot restrict input files with html. This can only be done on server side. accept value is can easily be modified on client side.

Comment: You could also have some javascript validation

Comment: @fiddler any javascript validation can be easily overcome...